# Can you help me identify this plant?

Tags: identification, weeds

Can you help me identify the big plant in the center right of the photograph? I planted a lot of different seeds but I don't think this is one of them, I think it's a weed.

*Click photograph for full size*

[image]

Comment: I see a lot of plants in your picture. Do you mean the big pointy star in the center, or the red flowery bits, or the spiky green one in the top-right corner, or those little leaves in the bottom-left?

Answer (score 6):

It's almost certainly an [Epilobium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilobium) (willowherb), probably [E. ciliatum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilobium_ciliatum) (common willowherb,
northern willowherb, fringed willowherb, etc., etc.). It's one of the most common garden
weeds in my own area (Seattle).

Comment: I, also, live in the Seattle area, and recognize your identification as correct. However, others reading your answer have no particular reason to believe you since the leaves and habit of the pictured plant resemble many plants in the *Lamiaceae* family: Basil, *Salvia*, etc. If, for example, you added that the leaf veins are odd in *Epilobium*. They don't go to the edges of the leaf, but form  loops inside the outer leaf margins (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilobium_angustifolium)), people would  would be able to correctly distinguish *Epilobiums* from similar plants.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a weed - I must have pulled out thousands of these. If memory serves, they eventually produce small, pale pink flowers, and they prefer to grow where the soil is either uncultivated, or damp, or has poor drainage. I have never yet managed to work out precisely which plant it is though, hopefully someone else might know.

Comment: A weed all right and with a flower reminiscent of a salvia.